# system("rvm 2.5.3 do ruby -v") leads to Warning! PATH is not properly set up

Tags: rvm, fish

Before marking this as duplicate let me explain:

When running `rvm 2.5.3 do ruby -v`, everything works well:

```
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

e.g. `ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.7.0dev (2019-03-18 trunk 67296) [x86_64-darwin17]`

But when running `ruby -e "system('rvm 2.5.3 do ruby -v')"` I get the big old `Warning! PATH is not properly set up` message (even though it executes correctly).

Comment: I would think ruby's `system` executes the command with /bin/sh, so you get your environment variables, but no fish functions.

Comment: Yeah did some testing and doesn't look like `system` executes in fish shell. But it exports the ENV variables to the spawn shell. So setting it in the parent shell makes it appear correctly in the spawn shells. Thanks for making me look into why this works. (e.g. what you said)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add `set -gx PATH $HOME/.rvm/bin $PATH` to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

Hope it helps others.